# Breaking the Parent-Child Relationship between Rectangles in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a report in SSRS and I am using rectangles as containers. I moved one of the rectangles a bit to close to another and now it has become the 'child' of the rectangle. This has been confirmed to me because in the properties dialogue box it indicates that this other rectangle is now the 'Parent'. However I can't seem to find any option to break this relationship as the box is greyed out in the properties section meaning I can't edit it. I thought there would be an option to ungroup the report items but I can't find anything, i'm hoping I am missing something rather simple.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio (I'm currently latest 2017 but 2015 was pretty much the same)

Open the Document Outliner from View->Other Windows or [Ctrl+Alt+T] for short. From there you can cut and paste objects between containers (e.g. rectangles).

Be warned

- There is no reliable drag and drop unfortunately. You must cut and paste in the document outline.
- It's a bit hit and miss. Sometimes you have to paste it onto a non-container object inside the container before it gets the hint, other times you just have to select the container you want when pasting.
- When moving between containers the object will end up being repositioned on the report, most annoying. If you drag it to the correct position you can end up dropping it back into the container you have just moved it from, so dragging can change container but rarely the way you want. The best way to move the object without risking container change is to change the Position Location in the object properties.

If your really brave you can always View Source and hack the RDL file directly.

Comment: Cut from body and past to new created rectangle is working . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think the only way to **fix** this is with the **UNDO**.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the parent after removing it from another container.

I would just move anything out of the rectangle and delete then create a new one.